# Loading jquery functions in Durandal - timing

Tags: jquery, requirejs, durandal

i'm having trouble figuring out when to load my jquery (from a separate js file into the durandal view).

i want to do things like attach event handlers like i would normally do using jquery's $(document).ready(function(){});

in shell.js i'm trying to load my other js file called unicorn.js by using requirejs like so:

```
define(function(require) {
    var router = require('durandal/plugins/router');
    var unicorn = require('../../content/js/unicorn');  

    return {
        router: router,        
        activate: function () {
            return router.activate('dashboard');
        },
        viewAttached: function () {
            console.log('viewattached');
            unicorn.setup();
        }
    };
});
```

it seems to load ok, but tells me that in my unicorn.js file, 'define is not defined'. here's what that looks like:

```
define(function () {    
    var unicorn = {         
        setup: function() {
            $('a').click(function(e) {
                //do stuff
            });
    };
});
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: i just figured it out - or at least one way to do it. i had my unicorn script defined in my bundled (third party) scripts. this was loading it early and thus not understanding the 'define' keyword. then i was loading it again in shell.js and it was working ok. all i had to do was remove it from the bundled scripts area.

Comment: you can answer your own questions and mark them as such. This will help others who may encounter a similar issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just figured it out - or at least one way to do it. i had my unicorn script defined in my bundled (third party) scripts. this was loading it early and thus not understanding the 'define' keyword. then i was loading it again in shell.js and it was working ok. all i had to do was remove it from the bundled scripts area.